# linq query, search by max date if previous date exists

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get three columns back from the database, DecalExpireDate, DecalExpireMonth and DecalExpireYear.  Basically, I'm trying to check if it has a previous expiration date and if it does, I need to get the latest expiration date, as it may have multiple previous expiration dates.

```
var previousExpirationDate = (from d in db.CT_Decals
      where d.TankID == decal.TankID
      && d.DecalStatus == "Approved"
      && d.DecalExpireDate == ((from dn in db.CT_Decals
                               where dn.TankID == decal.TankID
                               && dn.DecalStatus == "Approved"
                               select dn.DecalExpireDate).Max())
      select new 
      {
        d.DecalExpireDate,
        d.DecalExpireMonth,
        d.DecalExpireYear

      });
```

This query isn't working, can anybody see the problem?  I'm searching by TankID, Status = approved and then I try to use the max expirationDate.

Comment: doesn't bring anything back, if I check the immediate window it shows the text of the query

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
 var result = db.CT_Decals.Where(o => o.TankId ==  decal.TankId && o.DecalStatus == "Approved")
                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.DecalExpireDate)
                  .Select(o => new { o.DecalExpireDate,
                                     o.DecalExireMonth,
                                     o.DecalExireYear }).First()
```

or

```
var result = (from d in db.CT_Decals
                      where d.TankID == 1 && d.Status == "Approved"
                      orderby d.ExpireDate descending
                      select new { d.DecalExpireDate, 
                                   d.DecalExpireMonth, 
                                   d.ExpireDate }).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's with the that max function couldn't be translated to `Sql` in the scope that you need so you could try like this

```
 var previousExpirationDate = (from d in db.CT_Decals
  where d.TankID == decal.TankID
  && d.DecalStatus == "Approved"
  && d.DecalExpireDate == ((from dn in db.CT_Decals
                           where dn.TankID == decal.TankID
                           && dn.DecalStatus == "Approved"
                           order by dn.DecalExpireDate
                           select dn.DecalExpireDate).First())
  select new 
  {
    d.DecalExpireDate,
    d.DecalExpireMonth,
    d.DecalExpireYear

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `Max` may be the problem in your example, it would be nice to find a way to use it properly because it is faster than sorting.  How about:

*Edit:* this answer only returns the DecalExpireDate

```
var previousExpirationDate = (from d in db.CT_Decals
      where d.TankID == decal.TankID
      && d.DecalStatus == "Approved"
      select new 
      {
        d.DecalExpireDate,
        d.DecalExpireMonth,
        d.DecalExpireYear
      }).Max(d => d.DecalExpireDate);
```

For this version you will have to test to see if it's worth making an extra call to the database to avoid sorting:

```
var latestDate = (from d in db.CT_Decals
      where d.TankID == decal.TankID
      && d.DecalStatus == "Approved"
      select d.DecalExpireDate).Max();

var previousExpirationDate = (from d in db.CT_Decals
      where d.TankID == decal.TankID
      && d.DecalStatus == "Approved"
      && d.DecalExpireDate == latestDate
      select new 
      {
        d.DecalExpireDate,
        d.DecalExpireMonth,
        d.DecalExpireYear
      }).First();
```

Comment: how do I access the values now?  So if I want to get the DecalExpireDate or DecalExpireMonth, etc.....